# vue-cli: How to reinitialize after closed development session?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

This is probably a very basic question, but I'm trying to re-initialize a vue-cli development session after having closed my terminal window / restarted my computer, etc. So initially, I did:

```
$ vue init webpack my-project
```

to build the first session, but after, for instance, restarting the computer, how can I come back to or reinitialize this session?

Comment: `vue init` creates a project template. Are you looking for `npm run dev`?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `vue init webpack my-project` will generate a new webpack project.

To actually run the project (in development):

```
$ npm run dev
```